# Wordpress - Open popup when pressing a button

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have this code in .php that retrieves a contact form:

```
    echo '<div class="hsk-column4 hsk-agency-inquiry-form">';
    echo hsk_agency_enquiry_form();
    echo '</div>';
```

How can I make a popup appear with the contact form when pressing a button with `id="btn-contact"`?

Thanks.

Comment: Please look at: [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are talking about Modals? Should help...

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with jQuery

PHP:

```
<button id="btn-contact">Open Contact</button>

<?php
    echo '<div class="hsk-column4 hsk-agency-inquiry-form">';
    echo hsk_agency_enquiry_form();
    echo '</div>';
?>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
$("body").on("click", function(){
$(".hsk-column4.hsk-agency-inquiry-form").removeClass("active-form");
});

$("#btn-contact").on("click", function(event){
$(".hsk-column4.hsk-agency-inquiry-form").addClass("active-form");
event.stopPropagation();
});

});
```

CSS:

```
.hsk-column4.hsk-agency-inquiry-form {
display: none;
}
.active-form {
display: block;
}
```